# iOS 3D Touch Support in Native Script

Tags: javascript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I want to utilize the 3D touch support in iOS through Native Script. Currently there is a [Plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-3dtouch) for Quick actions, however i want to listen to `ForceTouch` actions of iOS devices. I want to do this using native iOS API but i am not sure how to get started. 
There is another plugin for [Cordova](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-3dtouch) by the same author, where there is a function which we can listen for force touches like below:

```
ThreeDeeTouch.watchForceTouches(function(result) {
    console.log("force touch % " + result.force); // 84
    console.log("force touch timestamp " + result.timestamp); // 1449908744.706419
    console.log("force touch x coordinate " + result.x); // 213
    console.log("force touch y coordinate " + result.y); // 41
  });
```

**How can i access to 3D Touch API in NativeScript iOS**?

Answer (score 2):

Since force touch does not have a similar function in Android, there is no NativeScript abstraction. You will have to use the iOS libraries themselves.

[How to use Native Libraries](https://docs.nativescript.org/runtimes/ios/how-to/Use-Native-Libraries)

[iOS force Touch documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Adopting3DTouchOniPhone/)